# How to check Parameter List value in Oracle PL/SQL?

Tags: oracle, parameters, plsql, oracleforms

I created a param list and add some parameter, but when I want to check if the parameter and its value has been added, it cannot get the value I just added. What's wrong with the code :

```
IF NOT ID_NULL(GET_PARAMETER_LIST('RPT')) THEN
  DESTROY_PARAMETER_LIST('RPT');
END IF;
v_param_list := CREATE_PARAMETER_LIST('RPT');

ADD_PARAMETER(v_param_list,'PAR_WHERE',TEXT_PARAMETER,'WHERE ID = 1010');

BEGIN
   GET_PARAMETER_ATTR(v_param_list,'PAR_WHERE',v_param_type,v_temp);
   message('PAR_WHERE:'||v_temp);
EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
   message('Couldn''t get the value for : PAR_WHERE');
END;
```

How could I retrieve all the parameters and values in a param list ?

Comment: Where is TEXT_PARAMETER filled?
@Ben: Apparently these are standard Oracle Forms functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As GriffeyDog said, there is no way to retrieve parameter list items. I had the same problem and solved it by using the database. The only way is to use workarounds.
My solution is to pass an ID in a parameter list. This ID represents a pl/sql collection. Once the ID is retrieved is easy to get all collection keys or values.
If you need more details let me know as the code is years old.....

Comment: You are right, this piece of code is for Oracle forms, I was using parameter list to pass values. Finally replaced by using global variables.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where you've defined `v_param_type` and `v_temp`. `v_param_type` needs to be a number and `v_temp` a varchar2, and they are both `out` parameters.

Unfortunately, there is no way to retrieve all of the parameters from the `ParamList` without knowing the names of the parameters contained in it beforehand.

Comment: I defined v_param_type and v_temp, just didn't print them out. The problem here is strange, except the define v_param_type and v_temp, is there any other issues?